# Are co-ordinate systems within a fractal inhertly compressible due to them having non integer dimensions?

Tags: geometry, information-theory, fractals

This is a thought that I came up with while I was building a giant fractal in minecraft.

If you have a space of some sort you can also create a coordinate system for it.  At first I defined that as being a tupple of values that uniquely indicates each point in a space.  Then I realized that this definition had a problem as you can uniquely identify a point within an $\mathbb{R}^2$ space by using a space filling curve.  Which is not what you think of when you normally conceive of a co-ordinate system.

So I think there needs to be a further restriction. That if there are two points in the space then there should be a proportionate difference within the co-ordinates. With this restriction I think we get the requirement that for a 2D space you will need a tuple of two numbers and likewise for 3D and higher dimensions.

Now consider a space that is just points on the sierpinski carpet.  You are going to require 2 real numbers to indicate where you are but because there are so many forbidden spaces there are quite a lot of forbidden spaces.

I think this will result in the numbers being compressible in a shannon information sense. Is my supposition correct and is there a better and more standard way of expressing this idea?

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant, but you can describe a point in a Sierpiński carpet by a sequence of numbers from 1 to 8, in each case describing which of the eight smaller copies of the carpet contains the point. (The same strategy for a point in a full square would require a sequence of numbers from 1 to 9 to get the same level of precision.)

Comment: It is kind of relevant.  If you think about it you can number each cell with a pair of ternary digits.  In such a scheme,  such a scheme is equivalent to your full square model.  And the digits of the pairs can be assigned to an X or Y value and turned into a string that can be read as a real number.
In the sierpinski carpet the pair (1,1) is banned.

Comment: Which shows that the two values are not independent of each other.